# В индексе отсутствует параметр IN или OUT:: 1

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, sqlexception

Переписал проект со Spring Boot 1.5.6 на

```
'springBoot'                      : '2.2.4.RELEASE',
'springCloud'                     : 'Hoxton.RELEASE',
'oraSpringData'                   : '1.2.1.RELEASE',
'ojdbc'                           : '12.1.0.2',
```

запрос использует JdbcTemplate template;
имплементированный таким образом

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
public class JdbcConfig {

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
    }
}
```

сам запрос

использует

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(template)
                    .withCatalogName("имя каталога")
                    .withFunctionName("имя хранимой процедуры")
                    .declareParameters(памаетры для запроса);
```

запрос к БД (оракл) стал возвращать:

```
CallableStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [{? = call PKG_CS_FOR_PS.GETPAYMENTALIAS()}]; SQL state [99999]; error code [17041]; В индексе отсутствует параметр IN или OUT:: 1
```

Comment: У Вас параметров в запросе либо больше, либо меньше, чем Вы описываете в PreparedStatement, а потом передаёте фактически. Т.е. грубо говоря у Вас в preparedStatement описаны параметры :1 и :2 в запросе, а передаёте Вы только 1 или только 2.

Comment: да еслибы) откатываюсь на предыдущие версии spring и java 8 все ок. на java 11 и новом спринге вот такая бага. тут думаю нужно новый jdbc коннектор создавать.